# Remove CSS Margin

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble removing the margin from the top of my container in codeigniter it is something to do with the default css but do not know where would remove it from.

```
https://carrarawebsitesolutions.com/
```

You can have a look at the top and see what I mean. I have tried may ways and now think it is something to do with the codeigniter default css I in command area some where.

I have tried do add

```
body {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding 0px !important;
}
```

And still nothing

Comment: This comes from your `.header h1`. Anyway, it has nothing to do with codeigniter

Comment: Changed tags and title, as @Brewal is correct - this has nothing to do with CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `margin: 0;` to `.header h1`

That should fix it. Hope this helps and I would suggest starting off with the [Eric Meyer Reset.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)